# Libimobiledevice python bindings?

Tags: python

Could someone explain or put me in a direction where i can find information about how to use the python bindings of libimobiledevice for my application?

I already searched for a documentation and the like but i can't find anything at all.

Comment: Distribution of Linux? Python Version?

Comment: @Devraj He ask for how to use them, not now to install them or where to get them. I don't think those things are relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Edit November 2015: NoBugs added a link to an example of using the bindings in a comment: https://github.com/upbit/python-imobiledevice_demo

There doesn't seem to be any documentation for the Python bindings specifically. They use SWIG, and here is the source in case you read C: http://cgit.sukimashita.com/libimobiledevice.git/tree/swig/imobiledevice.i

There appears to be another project providing libimobile device wrappers: https://github.com/bryanforbes/imobilesync/. They may be easier to use, and you can probably read the code since it's Python.

The API is documented here: http://www.libimobiledevice.org/docs/html/files.html

If none of that helps, try asking about documentation in #libimobiledevice on irc.freenode.net.

Comment: looks like the python bindings have been removed from current versions.
http://cgit.sukimashita.com/libimobiledevice.git/commit/swig/imobiledevice.i?id=ef69484cd678ede814ebc5d46bf84969b8d96051

Comment: No they are not removed, and as of 1.2 they work okay - see https://github.com/upbit/python-imobiledevice_demo